# Galaxy Nexus (Specificaly) camera startPreview failed

Tags: android, camera, galaxy-nexus

I'm having a strange issue on a galaxy nexus when trying to have a live camera view in my app. I get this error in the log cat:

```
06-29 16:31:26.681 I/CameraClient(133): Opening camera 0
06-29 16:31:26.681 I/CameraHAL(133): camera_device open
06-29 16:31:26.970 D/DOMX    (133): ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore) - returning error: 0x80001005 - Error returned from OMX API in ducati
06-29 16:31:26.970 E/CameraHAL(133): Error while configuring rotation 0x80001005
06-29 16:31:27.088 I/am_on_resume_called(21274): [0,digifynotes.Activity_Camera]
06-29 16:31:27.111 V/PhoneStatusBar(693): setLightsOn(true)
06-29 16:31:27.205 E/CameraHAL(133): OMX component is not in loaded state
06-29 16:31:27.205 E/CameraHAL(133): setNSF() failed -22
06-29 16:31:27.205 E/CameraHAL(133): Error: CAMERA_QUERY_RESOLUTION_PREVIEW -22
06-29 16:31:27.252 I/MonoDroid(21274): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.Exception: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Exception' was thrown.
06-29 16:31:27.252 I/MonoDroid(21274): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (intptr,intptr) <0x00068>
06-29 16:31:27.252 I/MonoDroid(21274): at Android.Hardware.Camera.StartPreview () <0x0007f>
06-29 16:31:27.252 I/MonoDroid(21274): at DigifyNotes.CameraPreviewView.SurfaceChanged (Android.Views.ISurfaceHolder,Android.Graphics.Format,int,int) <0x000d7>
06-29 16:31:27.252 I/MonoDroid(21274): at Android.Views.ISurfaceHolderCallbackInvoker.n_SurfaceChanged_Landroid_view_SurfaceHolder_III (intptr,intptr,intptr,int,int,int) <0x0008b>
06-29 16:31:27.252 I/MonoDroid(21274): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.4c65d912-497c-4a67-9046-4b33a55403df (intptr,intptr,intptr,int,int,int) <0x0006b>
```

That very same source code works flawlessly on a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2X (4.0.4) and an LG G2X (2.3.7).
I will later test on a galaxy s4 if my friend lends it to me.

Galaxy Nexus runs Android 4.2.2 I believe.

Any one have any ideas?

EDIT: Here are my camera classes:

[Please note I am using mono]
[The formatting is more readable if you view it as raw]

Camera Activity: http://pastebin.com/YPcGXJRB

Camera Preview View: http://pastebin.com/zNf8AWDf

Comment: Could you add your camera class as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do this

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

to the manifest? It seems to me that for some reason it is an orientation problem...

Comment: Use portrait instead. I just picked landscape randomly.

Comment: can you post the Camera class?